# Regular Expression comparison in js

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>hhh</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

 <script>
  function myFunction() {
  var re1 =/./;
  var x = document.getElementById("fname");
  if(x.value==re1){
  var h = document.createElement("H1");
  var t = document.createTextNode(x.value);
  h.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(h);}

  else if (x.value=="## a"){
  var h = document.createElement("H2");
  var t = document.createTextNode(x.value);
  h.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(h);}
 }
 </script>

 </body>
```

The code in javascript , where I try to compare the x.value with regexp doesn't work. I am trying to make a markdown editor from scratch.Please help me with comparing (#string) with x.value and then output it as H1 heading. 
While the H2 part works, when I enter (# a).

Comment: You should read some documentation and examples on how to use regular expressions. Hint: `==` cannot be used to match strings against regular expressions. There are methods for that.

Comment: You should do it other way but yes you can use regex for this so this is simple example of working bold `data.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/g, "<b>$1</b>)`

Comment: HTML is easily parsed. ``HtmlParser`` works great. If you are not allowed to use a library, then you should create a simple parser yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `if (x.value==re1)`, you are attempting to compare the equality of a string and a RegExp object, which will always be false. Instead, use the RegExp object's `.test()` method:

`if (re1.test(x.value))`

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

RegExp.prototype.test() will perform better in your case than using String.prototype.match(), since the latter (unnecessarily) computes and returns an array of identified matches within the string, when all you need to know is whether or not there was a match.

Comment: Is the issue resolved entirely? Let me know, and select this answer as correct if so.

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
if (x.match(/ ./g))
```

or

```
if (x.match(rel))
```

Comment: /  ./g.test(str) // will return if sting has match

Answer (score -2):

You're checking a string against a regexp object, so you'll want something like the following to check RegExp against RegExp:

```
if(new RegExp(x.value) === re1){
    // Match
}
```

Comment: Is not what OP is looking for, and would never be true anyway.